# ¿Como agregar favicon en laravel?

Tags: html, laravel

Estoy intentando cambiar el favicon en un proyecto laravel, pero por alguna razón no funciona...
Esto e lo que agregué en el head

```
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
```

[image: Pero así se mantiene]

[image: Ubicación actualizada]

Comment: No, no hay ninguno

Comment: El link no tiene acceso a ese directorio. Tienes que poner el favicon en la capeta /public

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero aun así no funciona. Acabo de resubir la foto de los documentos

Comment: Abre las developer tools del navegador para ver que *favicon* te esta cargango: Chorme pestaña "Network" y actualiza, puedes filtrar por "Img" / Firerox pestaña "Red", filtro "Imágenes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hola debes agregar en el header de tu app esto:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{ asset('/img/favicon_192x192.png') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="192x192" href="{{ asset('/img/favicon_192x192.png') }}">
```

luego debes correr los comandos:

```
php artisan config:cache 
php artisan cache:clear
```

recargas la aplicacion y deberias poder ver el icono que pusiste, espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 3):

No uses rutas relativas, usa el helper `asset()`:

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.ico') }}">
```

Donde el icono se encuentra en "public/images/favicon.ico".

Comment: Hola, lo hice pero me sigue apareciendo el logo por defecto de xampp

Comment: Debe aparecer el icono con la ubicación indicada, comprueba que no es el de Xampp y prueba borrando las vistas por si no se actualizaron: `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Ya lo hice, pero sigue sin funcionar. Agrego fotos de donde tengo el documento, quizás ahi está el error

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto

```
<link rel="shortcat icon" href="images/favicon.jpg">
```

A mi me funciona así

Comment: <link rel="shortcat icon" href="images/favicon.jpg">

Comment: Hola, tampoco ha funcionado, aun me aparece el logo por defecto de xampp